# Checking whether a date is within the next week

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, date, certificates

Trying to create a script for automatic SSL renewal with LetsEncrypt.

Daily script begins with checking when SSL expiry is:

`response="$(openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in ~/letsencrypt/www.mydomain.com/cert.pem)"`

`$response` is `notAfter=May 9 19:27:44 2018 GMT`

I would like it to compare with today's date and check whether the time difference is less or equal to 7 days. Pseudocode:

`if [$response is less than 7 days away from today]
then
 cd ~/letsencrypt $$ ~/dehydrated/dehydrated --cron --domain www.mydomain.com --out . --challenge http-01`

How do I go about doing this?

I tried to convert `$response` into a more workable format through `date -d` but got a `date: extra operand ‘19:27:44’` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will address your actual concern rather than the specific question you asked: `dehydrated --cron` already does the date checking for you.

Documentation:

> `--cron` (`-c`)    Sign/renew non-existent/changed/expiring certificates.

Code:

```
# Check expire date of existing certificate
if [[ -e "${cert}" ]]; then
  echo " + Checking expire date of existing cert..."
  valid="$("${OPENSSL}" x509 -enddate -noout -in "${cert}" | cut -d= -f2- )"

  printf " + Valid till %s " "${valid}"
  if "${OPENSSL}" x509 -checkend $((RENEW_DAYS * 86400)) -noout -in "${cert}"; then
    printf "(Longer than %d days). " "${RENEW_DAYS}"
    if [[ "${force_renew}" = "yes" ]]; then
      echo "Ignoring because renew was forced!"
    else
      # Certificate-Names unchanged and cert is still valid
      echo "Skipping renew!"
```

(https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated/blob/master/dehydrated#L1234-L1253)

`RENEW_DAYS` appears to default to 30, but you can override it using a configuration file; quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated#config):

> dehydrated is looking for a config file in a few different places, it will use the first one it can find in this order:
>
> - `/etc/dehydrated/config`
> - `/usr/local/etc/dehydrated/config`
> - The current working directory of your shell
> - The directory from which dehydrated was run

The sample config file there contains this line:

```
# Minimum days before expiration to automatically renew certificate (default: 30)
#RENEW_DAYS="30"
```

To lower the value from the default 30 to 7 days, for example, you would edit the second line to be:

```
RENEW_DAYS="7"
```

Comment: Awesome! So I just need to run the upgrade command everyday, pretty much. Bonus question - now how do I make an `if then` statement based on **that** response - so example, if the certificate does renew then run X command?

Comment: @DDiran sounds like a new question! :)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Noted, working on that now... Could you please share more detail on overriding the `RENEW_DATES` though? :D

Comment: @DDiran, see dhag's recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

Determine the number of seconds sinds 1/1/1970 for the expiry date, for now, 
and divide the difference by the number of seconds in a day.

```
$ TZ=GMT date -d "May 9 19:27:44 2018 GMT" '+%s'
1525894064
$ TZ=GMT date '+%s'                             
1518192447
$ expr \( 1525894064 - 1518192447 \) / 86400
89
```

Comment: Thanks, it **does** work, but not when I replace "May 9 19:27:44 2018 GMT" with $response. How come?

Comment: You need to drop the "notAfter=".  use " ${response/*=/}"

Comment: yeah, done that, still getting the `date: extra operand ‘19:27:44’ ` error

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 1):

The commands below will check the date provided by the openssl command against the date "7 days from now"; if the openssl date (in seconds since the epoch) is less than 7 days from now (in seconds since the epoch), the `if` command will succeed and you can do what you need to do:

```
response="$(openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in ~/letsencrypt/www.mydomain.com/cert.pem)"
responsetime=${response##notAfter=}
responsetz={$responsetime##* }
if [ $(date -d "$responsetime" +%s) -lt $(TZ=$responsetz date -d "now + 7 days" +%s) ]
then
   ## do the needful
fi
```

The first assignment (after getting the $response) strips off the leading "notAfter=" text. The second assignment captures the timezone of the response; this could be simplified if it's always GMT.

The two date commands ask (GNU) date for the time in seconds since the epoch for the openssl date and for "now + 7 days", being careful to set the timezone for the 2nd call to the timezone reported by the openssl command.